# Deploying a database to SQL Azure through SSMS fails with views in the database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I'm having issues deploying databases to SQL Azure DB from SQL Server Management Studio using the Tasks > "Deploy Databases to Microsoft SQL Azure" option path.  I notice this tends to fail if the database has views. Is this a well-known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider *not* using SSMS and use **Microsoft Data Migration Assistant** (DMA) instead. DMA is the easiest way to migrate a database to Azure SQL Database. It gives you an assessment of the database and tells you about possible blocking points and existent incompatibilities of the database with Azure SQL Database. You can download DMA from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).

Comment: Then, why does this option exist in SSMS?

Comment: SSMS is an option, I just provided you the easiest and most successful way of doing it.  If you still want to try SSMS please download the latest version to have the best user experience. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: @Alberto Morillo; I had problems using SSMS (the newest version 17.9.1), as I got this error; Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
Error Deploy72002: DeploymentContributor 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.Extensions.CreateDatabaseWithCustomEditionDeploymentModifier' threw exception. Message is: 'Metoden blev ikke fundet: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlFragment 

Your answer solved my problem. DMA works.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @HenrikStaunPoulsen You are welcome! let me know if you have any issues going forward. Have a great day!